# Angular How to combine Interval with Zip to show loading

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a page which has to be update every minute, but I have several http request.
So I'm trying use Interval with zip operator.
How Can I combine these two to show my loading "isLoading" after all the request?

This is what I got :

```
    isLoading = true;
    source = interval(60000);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const responseZipado = zip(
      this.monitorService.getSMPPstatus(),
      this.homeService.getCampaignsToday(),
      this.monitorService.getPerfomance(),
    );

    
      responseZipado.subscribe((valores) => {
      this.statusSMPP = valores[0],
      this.dataSourceToday = valores[1],
      this.perfomanceDataSource = valores[2],
    });

  }
```

should I use other operator than Zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` for parallel http requests because you need value after loading all requests.

**Example:**

```
interval(60000).pipe(
  tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
  switchMap(() => forkJoin([
    this.monitorService.getSMPPstatus().pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
    this.homeService.getCampaignsToday().pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
    this.monitorService.getPerfomance().pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
  ])),
).subscribe((valores) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.statusSMPP = valores[0];
  this.dataSourceToday = valores[1];
  this.perfomanceDataSource = valores[2];
})
```

Comment: thanks for you help.
Actually I need the loading to disappear after all my request.
If I use forkjoin, if one of my request get error, all of my request will be canceled, right?
That is why i'm using Zip instead of forkjoin

Comment: Then you can use ```catchError``` or ```onErrorResumeNext``` in ```forkJoin``` for every request, this way you won't lose the whole result ```forkJoin``` and wait for all requests to be processed.
Example: ```this.monitorService.getSMPPstatus().pipe(catchError(error => of(error)))```